# Prevent maven module from being built with no activated profile

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I have a multi-module maven project with parent POM. One child of project is customized for different environments by profiles and parent pom also build needed modules depending on selected environment (profile).

I want to prevent building (read as "to run mvn package" in child module) customized child project without profile activated, because there is no "generic" or "default" version for environment. Another words, I want to force developer to use environment-dependent profile.

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: You can use [Maven Enforcer](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireActiveProfile.html). Perfect use case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Maven Enforcer](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireActiveProfile.html) is made just for this requirement. Simply add the required profiles.

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>enforce-all-profiles-are-activated</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <requireActiveProfile>
                  <profiles>first,second</profiles>
                </requireActiveProfile>
              </rules>
              <fail>true</fail>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```